# Circular queue implement use single linked list vs double linked list vs array?

Tags: java, algorithm

In order to implement a circular queue do you use a single linked list or double linked list or array?when and why?

What I am basically trying to say is

Array vs linked list fixed size more memory for pointers yes I understand

But when do you use double link list to implement a circular queue over a single link list and vice versa??

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I would choose array, because I care so much about cache miss.  (I feel that this will lead to a subjective argument.)      Agree with Tim Biegeleisen, you should discover most pros & cons from experimenting it by yourself.  IMHO, it is the best way to learn this kind of thing.  This might be a reason of the downvote storm .

Comment: @Tim The question is not asking for code, so asking what the OP has written so far is wrong. The OP is asking what kind of data structure would be most appropriate, which is a good question.

Comment: What are your goals here? For what do you need the circular queue? Usually, you'd go with an array, especially when memory usage is important. This will of course result in a static size. If you use lists for dynamic size, it needs only to be single linked if it has nothing more than the regular queue operations, that is enqueue and dequeue. A double linked list allows to traverse it in both directions. Linked lists obviously make insertion easy, but that is usually not what one would understand when he hears "queue".

Comment: @Raedwald I did not downvote, just left a comment.  I have upvoted the question.

Comment: I use `java.util.ArrayDeque`. It’s very well suited for the job. If I was to make my own implementation (like for a school assignment), I would probably choose a similar one, that is, in an array.

Comment: If the queue size varies very much, like from 1 million elements down to 3 elements, and you need to free up the space, that *might* be an arguments for a linked list. Then again, why would you need to free up the space? RAM is cheap these days.

Answer (score 1):

A doubly linked list requires extra storage and CPU work to maintain the back links, when compared to a singly linked list. A singly linked list requires extra storage and CPU to maintain the forward links, when compared to an array. The numerous small objects for a linked list requires extra storage (each object has some storage overhead) and garbage collector work, when compared to an array. So using an array has superior performance.

However, using an array requires some extra logic, which can be tricky for a beginner, to make a linear array behave like a circular structure. So you might want to write an inefficient linked list implementation first, then modify that to be efficient.

Comment: Also, an array has a fixed length

Comment: Also, there are 2 classes of algorithms for writing these, recursive and linear. I'd recommend trying out the linear first and then the recursive.

Comment: When do you use double link list over single link list to implement circular queue?

When do you use single link list over double link list to implement circular queue?

Same comparison over an array

Comment: If you can see a specific need for going backward through the list, make it doubly linked. If you cannot, don’t.

Comment: When do you think you would need to go back in a circular queue ?

Comment: Rarely for a circular queue. Maybe if you need to be able to undo the last _n_ additions to the queue, for example.